# how to un-hide the Menubar in Okular

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gui, okular, toolbar

In Okular, the visibility of toolbars and panels can be toggled via *Settings* on the Menubar. From this menu, even the Menubar itself can be hidden, which leaves me with no way to restore it.

**How do I restore the Menubar when it is hidden?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is the default keyboard shortcut to hide/unhide the Menubar